# How to fetch all the channels from an audio session in win32 api?

Tags: c++, winapi, audio

I want to control all the app volumes programatically in my cpp program. Basically i would like to be able to control independently each app volume as the windows sound mixer does.
[image]

from what I read in the windows api doc, I first need to fetch the default endpoint and then the default audio session.
I'm yet done with this I think, that's what I have :

```cpp
#include <mmdeviceapi.h>
#include <endpointvolume.h>
#include <Audioclient.h>
#include <audiopolicy.h>
#include <iostream>


int main() {
    HRESULT hr = CoInitialize(NULL);

    if (hr != S_OK) {
        std::cout << "error initializing : " << hr << std::endl;
        return -1;
    }
    else
        std::cout << "successfully initialized\n";

    IMMDeviceEnumerator* pEnumerator = NULL;

    hr = CoCreateInstance(__uuidof(MMDeviceEnumerator), NULL, CLSCTX_ALL, __uuidof(IMMDeviceEnumerator), (LPVOID*)&pEnumerator);
    if (hr != S_OK) {
        std::cout << "error creating instance : " << hr << std::endl;
        return -1;
    }
    else {
        std::cout << "successfully created instance\n";
    }

    IMMDevice* pDevice = NULL;

    hr = pEnumerator->GetDefaultAudioEndpoint(EDataFlow::eRender, ERole::eConsole, &pDevice);
    pEnumerator->Release();
    pEnumerator = NULL;

    if (hr != S_OK) {
        std::cout << "error getting default endpoint device : " << hr << std::endl;
        return -1;
    }
    else {
        LPWSTR id = NULL;
        pDevice->GetId(&id);
        DWORD state = 0;
        pDevice->GetState(&state);
        std::cout << "found device 0x" << id << " with state " << state << std::endl;
    }

    IAudioClient* audioClient = NULL;

    hr = pDevice->Activate(__uuidof(IAudioClient), CLSCTX_ALL, NULL, (LPVOID*)&audioClient);

    if (hr != S_OK) {
        std::cout << "failed instantiating audio client " << hr << std::endl;
        pDevice->Release();
        pDevice = NULL;
        return -1;
    }
    else {
        std::cout << "successfully instantiated audio client" << std::endl;
    }

    IAudioSessionManager2* sessionManager = NULL;
    hr = pDevice->Activate(__uuidof(IAudioSessionManager2), CLSCTX_ALL, NULL, (LPVOID*) &sessionManager);
    pDevice->Release();
    pDevice = NULL;

    if (hr != S_OK) {
        std::cout << "failed instantiating session manager " << hr << std::endl;
        return -1;
    }
    else {
        std::cout << "successfully instantiated sessionManager" << std::endl;
    }

    IAudioSessionControl2* sessionControl = NULL;
    hr = sessionManager->GetAudioSessionControl(&GUID_NULL, FALSE, (IAudioSessionControl**)&sessionControl);
    if (hr != S_OK) {
        std::cout << "failed retrieving session control " << hr << std::endl;
        return -1;
    }

    LPWSTR sessionId = NULL;
    hr = sessionControl->GetSessionIdentifier(&sessionId);
    if (hr != S_OK) {
        std::cout << "failed retrieving session id " << hr << std::endl;
        return -1;
    }

    GUID sessionGuid = {};
    hr = CLSIDFromString(sessionId, &sessionGuid);
    if (hr != S_OK) {
        std::cout << "failed transforming to GUID " << hr << std::endl;
        // got fail here the error code is CO_E_CLASSSTRING -> hr = -2147221005
        return -1;
    }

    //need GUID to initialize audio client or get service will fail
    IChannelAudioVolume* channelVolume = NULL;
    audioClient->GetService(__uuidof(IChannelAudioVolume), (LPVOID*)&channelVolume);

    // is there any better way to list all the channels so i can get the name or the process id of each channel
    // is channel the right object to use in this case

    sessionControl->Release();
    sessionControl = NULL;
    sessionManager->Release();
    sessionManager = NULL;
    audioClient->Release();
    audioClient = NULL;

    CoUninitialize();

    return 0;
}
```

the program fails when it reaches the id to guid part of the code. How to solve that and will the IChannelAudioVolume allow me to change specific app volumes.
I would also appreciate any samples if existing.

Comment: You can check if this works for you: `hr = sessionControl->QueryInterface(__uuidof(IChannelAudioVolume), (LPVOID*)&channelVolume);
 UINT32 chlCount;
 hr = channelVolume->GetChannelCount(&chlCount);`

Comment: The particular `CO_E_CLASSSTRING` error code is [documented](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/combaseapi/nf-combaseapi-clsidfromstring) to mean *"The class string was improperly formatted."* In other words: You are passing a GUID that's improperly formatted (e.g. without enclosing braces) or a string, that doesn't represent a GUID at all.

Comment: @RitaHan-MSFT thanks for your comment, I finally managed to do what I wanted using IsimpleAudio volume instead of IChannelAudioVolume, I'll will answer my question in a few days, Thanks for helping me and now I have the answer, I assume that the question wasn't really clear

Comment: @R.LM You can [answer your own question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer) for sharing your solution with others who are searching on the same issue.